# Google Cloud Load Balancer: internalForwardingRulesLimitsExceeded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-internal-load-balancer

Since a couple of days, I'm facing the following error when trying to deploy a new service which uses internal load balancer on Google Cloud:

> Error creating load balancer (will retry): failed to ensure load
>   balancer for service production-trading/authentication: googleapi:
>   Error 403: You cannot create any more internal forwarding rules in
>   this project, as the limit of 20.0 is reached.,
>   **internalForwardingRulesLimitsExceeded**

From the [Google Cloud doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/internal/#limits), the limit should be 50.

Also, usually, I ask to increase the quota, but this time I didn't find any associated quota for this feature in the [quotas section](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas).

Any idea ? thanks

Comment: To answer your question, it requires further inspection of your project. Open an issue from the [Issue Tracker] and somebody from the support team will contact you for further investigation. [Issue Tracker]:https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: the documentation might simply be inaccurate. pretty sure I've seen this question before.